# How to pass multiple origin values in googleapis?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using google api in my dot net MVC4 application. When I try to retrieve values for my search using google apis distance matrix with multiple origin values, my code is giving me results of first origin ignoring the latter one. How to fix this. This is the url

```
    http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=**BOCA RAYTON|33401**&destinations=300 North Dixie Highway, Suite 350, WPB&mode=driving&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial
```

look at my origins value, I'm passing BOCA RAYTON and 33401 with pipe separation. The origin value is a string which is like "BOCA RAYTON|33401". I tried replacing pipe with comma which didn't work too. Any suggestions please?

Comment: That works for me, can't find the destination: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=BOCA%20RAYTON|33401&destinations=300%20North%20Dixie%20Highway,%20Suite%20350,%20WPB&mode=driving&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your origin value: when requesting the following

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=BOCA RAYTON|33401&destinations=300 North Dixie Highway, Suite 350, WPB&mode=driving&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial
```

I got:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <origin_address>Boca Raton, Floride, États-Unis</origin_address>
    <origin_address>West Palm Beach, Floride 33401, États-Unis</origin_address>
    <destination_address/>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>NOT_FOUND</status>
        </element>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>NOT_FOUND</status>
        </element>
    </row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

The problem is around the destination address, which is not resolved, so results not found.

If you put a correct destination (like `300 North Dixie Highway, 33401`):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=BOCA+RATON|33401&destinations=300%20North%20Dixie%20Highway,%2033401&mode=driving&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial
```

You will have your result:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <origin_address>Boca Raton, Floride, États-Unis</origin_address>
    <origin_address>West Palm Beach, Floride 33401, États-Unis</origin_address>
    <destination_address>300 North Dixie Highway, West Palm Beach, Floride 33401, États-Unis</destination_address>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>1623</value>
                <text>27 minutes</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>43944</value>
                <text>27,3 miles</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>0</value>
                <text>1 minute</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>4</value>
                <text>13 pieds</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
    </row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```